# Cannot see parameter values used for Facebook Purchase Event - Facebook Pixel

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, facebook-analytics

I have integrated Facebook Purchase event for our website using Facebook event manager and Google tag manger.
I have set two parameters related with order id and currency used for the purchase. I can see that the purchase event works properly and the parameter consists of proper values when I make a purchase and see it in real time with the help of datalayer, Facebook pixel helper (Chrome extension) and the Overview tab present in Facebook event manager console. However when I view my purchase event in Facebook analytics I cannot find the section where the parameter values of my purchase event in Facebook analytics are recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1 - Create a variable in GTM for Transaction Value

2 - In custom HTML Tag put the variable you had just created in step 1 in value.

EG:

```
<script>
  fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: {{Transaction Value}}
```

Comment: Variable is already created and the values are getting properly reflected as present in the datalayer. The problem is that I can't see the parameters value when I check it in Facebook Analytics

Answer (score 0):

I am not a FB Analytics expert but I don't think the FB Analytics provide these parameters.

Comment: Yes, I have used custom parameters. The value is recorded against these parameters when viewed in real time. I need to find the section where I can find the values related with them in my Facebook Analytics account by specifying a date range